# Porting MFC application from visual studio 2005 to 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, visual-studio-2005, porting

I am porting an mfc application from VS 2005 to VS 2015. I simply upgraded by opening the application in VS 2015. It built successfully with some minor changes. I am facing a Problem during runtime. The mainframe class OnCreate method Fails. It simply Returns without creating a mainframe handle. I also observed that in VS 2005 the mainframe is inherited from CMDIFrameWnd class while in VS2015 it is inherited from CMDIFrameWndEx class. I have changed that and tried as well but still the same error. Has someone else also faced a similar Problem? Can anyone direct me to the possible error and fix for the same?

Comment: Stepping through thge relevant MFC code should give you some hints.

Comment: I have tried that but unable to figure out.

Comment: You can continue to use `CMDIFrameWnd` if you want! Changing to `CMDIFrameWndEx` will require other changes in your code, like changing the application base from `CWinApp` to `CWinAppEx`. Check the documentation for `CMDIFrameWnd` ***thoroughly*** and check the values of all your parameters. Things will have changed in the 10 years between VS/MFC releases.

Comment: Maybe also check your resource scripts: if you use `LoadFrame()` then resource requirements for `MENU` (and others) may have changed.